# perl module calls methods from a package that isn't imported

Tags: perl, import, dependencies

<strike>I was appalled to discover today that one of my perl modules uses another module, but doesn't import it.</strike>

**However, I was shocked when I realized that this has never caused any problems!**

The code is something like:

```
package This;
# no import for OTHER !!

sub new {
    ... implementation ...
    my $something = OTHER->new(@arguments); # no error!
    ... more implementation ...
}
```

**So what gives?**  None of `This`'s imports import `OTHER` -- that was the first thing I checked.

Could it be that if the code that imports `This` also imports `OTHER`, `OTHER` is available to `This`?

---

Clarification of question:

- `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are modules.
- in **X**: `use Y;`
- in **X**: `use Z;`
- `Y` *does not* `use` `Z`

**Does `Y` have access to the functions and methods in `Z` (and vice versa)?**

Comment: It's being imported somewhere. I suspect if you boil this down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you'll find that's the case.

Comment: @BrianRoach -- just to clarify for me:  if X imports Y, and X also imports Z, then Y has access to Z without importing it (and vice versa)?

Comment: I believe yes, once a package is imported it's available globally because of the way OO was sort of bolted onto perl but I'd have to test it; I haven't really been writing much perl for a couple years and it's a bit rusty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the term "import" is a bit misleading.

> Does `Y` have access to `Z` without importing it (and vice versa)?

Yes, more or less. `use`ing a module just loads it into the current script; all `use`d modules are loaded into the same script, so can see each other (provided they're `use`d in the right order).

But true *imports* — the things that a module actually *exports*, so that they're copied into the `use`ing module's namespace — will *only* be copied into the `use`ing module's namespace.

For example, consider this Perl script:

```
use Time::HiRes 'time';

package Foo;

sub time1() { return time(); } # calls the built-in time() function
sub time2() { return Time::HiRes::time(); }


package main;

print Foo::time1(), "\n"; # prints (e.g.) 1323048440
print Foo::time2(), "\n"; # prints (e.g.) 1323048440.80571
print time(), "\n";       # prints (e.g.) 1323048440.8061
```

It `use`s the `Time::HiRes` module, and tells it to export `Time::HiRes::time` into the current namespace (the main namespace), overwriting the built-in `time`. (`Time::HiRes::time` is like `time`, but it has sub-second resolution; it'll give something like `1323048440.80571` instead of just `1323048440`.) So package `Foo` can see `Time::HiRes`, and anything within `Time::HiRes`, such as its `time`; but it has to explicitly specify that, by explicitly writing `Time::HiRes::time`.

(Note: I wrote the above as a single script, for simplicity of description, but the same thing happens when `Foo` is defined in `Foo.pm` and loaded using `use Foo;`.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on `import` -- I've attempted to clarify the OP.  I believe the first part of your answer solves my specific problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least when you use indirect package and object syntax. From calls like

```
OtherPackage->method()
$anOtherPackageObject->method()
```

Perl can resolve a fully qualified subroutine name (`&OtherPackage::method` in both of the above cases) and invoke the subroutine from anywhere.